# Windows 10 reboots and freeze randomly

Tags: freeze, reboot

First config:

Motherboard: MSI B550M PRO-VDH WIFI

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 3100
GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 1050Ti Low Profile
RAM: 2 x 8 GB HYPERX HX432C16PB3A/8
PSU: Chieftec CSN-650C 650W
SSD: ADATA SWORDFISH m.2 2280PCIe Gen3x4
Body: Aerocool Playa Slim
```

At the moment, I sometimes have random reboots or freezes.

At first I noticed high temperatures while cooling the CPU by stock cooling, but this is due to low airflow in the body (idle 60C). I tried to fix this by turning all the fans to maximum, after that I hit 50C at idle (for clarification, idle means desktop after running with wallpaper engine and transparent start on 4k 60fps TV).

I haven't noticed any problems with the games on this list:

- Nehrim (moded Oblivon, 4k, ultra high, 60 fps)
- Natural Selection 2 (1k, low, 60fps)
- Planetside 2 (1k, low, high draw distance, 60 fps)

For now, freezes and reboots in these games:

- Europe Truck Simulator 2 (4k, ultra high, 30-60 fps)

Freezes and reboots happen randomly, sometimes 1 hour, sometimes 6 hours like today.

For now, I have checked these parameters:

- max CPU temp using stress test - 95C and no reboot/freeze
- max CPU temp playing ETS2 - 75C and no reboot/freeze
- max GPU temp playing ETS2 - 75C and no reboot/freeze
- RAM test by MemTest - found 1 error (don't know details)
- RAM test by MemTest86 - waiting for result at this moment (I will update this)

The motherboard was updated a month ago, I will try to update it today but not sure which part is causing the problem, anyone can help?

Comment: Yes, update UEFI and drivers, namely Nvidia's. And if error on RAM, replace it, obviously

Comment: RAM problems is one possibility, but let MemTest86 run for many hours, overnight if possible. When the computer is available: (1) Look for errors in the Event Viewer, (2) Run `chkdsk`, (3) Check the SMART status of the disk (for example using [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), (4) Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc yes, I have errors in Event Viewer but no details in there, just critical shutdown by failure, error or lack of power

Comment: @ChanganAuto I know it, but I need to w8 for memtest86, because it a better tool but it will take longer.

Comment: Since all other apps and games work *except* for *Europe Truck Simulator*, I'd expect an issue with that version of the game. Either it might be damaged, or you need a newer version compatible with current configuration. Look online for discussions of the issue, or check with the maker.

Comment: Memtest86 - zero errors

Comment: After updating all drivers, i have reboots and freezes more often, and I had blue screen once

Comment: Changed PSU doesn't fix issue ...

Answer (score -2):

It's the motherboard. See a plethora of other similar posts about this mobo on the usual sites [1] -- changing psu doesn't fix what seems on the surface to be a power issue. Many people have this exact same problem in the newegg reviews on this board too. [2]

Swapping mobo fixes the issue.

[1] E.g., https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/pc-reboots-randomly-with-ryzen-3600-and-b550m-pro-vdh-wifi.344757/; https://www.reddit.com/r/MSI_Gaming/comments/irfpms/new_build_help_constant_reboots/; https://www.reddit.com/r/MSI_Gaming/comments/ip4fhs/help_problems_with_my_build_possibly_msi_b550m/; https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/new-build-highly-unstable-ryzen-5-3600-msi-b550m-pro-vdh-wifi.3690564/; https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/new-build-highly-unstable-ryzen-5-3600-msi-b550m-pro-vdh-wifi.3690564/; https://linustechtips.com/topic/1319374-msi-b550m-pro-vdh-wifi-ryzen-5600x-random-restarts/

[2] https://www.newegg.com/msi-b550m-pro-vdh-wifi/p/N82E16813144331

Comment: Can you post a 2-3 links to that threads?

Comment: Edited to add links